# filtering web.xml with maven causes font not loaded

Tags: maven, jsf-2, font-face

I develop a web application with JSF2 and Maven 3.
In my application, I use a custom font with the following code in my css:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'another_shabby';
src: url("#{resource['fonts:anothershabby_trial-webfont.eot']}");
src: url("#{resource['fonts:anothershabby_trial-webfont.eot']}?#iefix")
    format('embedded-opentype'),
    url("#{resource['fonts:anothershabby_trial-webfont.woff']}")
    format('woff'),
    url("#{resource['fonts:anothershabby_trial-webfont.ttf']}")
    format('truetype'),
    url("#{resource['fonts:anothershabby_trial-webfont.svg']}#WebSymbolsRegular")
    format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}
```

the font files are in my `resources` folder, in the directory:`webapp/resources/fonts`

Now, I have a problem which seems to be caused by Maven...

I have added a filter in maven to parse the web.xml in order to dynamically switch the context-param `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` between Development and Production, according to a Maven profile.

Here is my pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <properties>
        <jsfProjectStage>Development</jsfProjectStage>
    </properties>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

The web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>${jsfProjectStage}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

When I use this configuration, the font is not loaded properly, but if I remove the filter in the pom and the context-param is *"hard-coded"*, everything works fine... I tested on Safari (Mac + iPhone) and Chrome.

Is there a problem in my configuration? Did I miss something? Is it a known problem?...

Comment: How does your css look like after filtering? And you can exclude resources from being 'filtered'... That might be a solution to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some researches, I found an other solution to my problem. I post it, just in case:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Yes but my "reputation" score is not high enough to vote up answers for now... sorry

Answer (score 0):

You're filtering your binary files (i.e., the *font* file).

Check out the guide how to exclude / include only selected resources https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/binaries-filtering.html

As it says

> To prevent corrupting your binary files when filtering is enabled, you can configure a list of file extensions that will not be filtered.

do

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>            
        <configuration>
          <!-- the default value is the filter list under build -->
          <!-- specifying a filter will override the filter list under build -->
          <filters>
            <filter>properties/config.prop</filter>
          </filters>
          <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            <!-- default value contains jpg,jpeg,gif,bmp,png -->
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
          </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
          <webResources>
            <resource>
              <directory>resource2</directory>
              <!-- it's not a good idea to filter binary files -->
              <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
              <directory>configurations</directory>
              <!-- enable filtering -->
              <filtering>true</filtering>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>**/properties</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

As a rule of thumb, filter as least files as possible (to get the best performance) and let maven copy the majority of files. When a file is filtered, it has to be processed character by character (according to given charset) while when not filtered, it's simply copied on a filesystem.